# Questions about Macro Definitions in C/C++ for a specific expression

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, ternary-operator

I am trying to understand some C++ code and this piece of code is confusing me.

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define ukd_assert(expr) \ 
((void)((expr) ? 0 : (Assert::failedAssert(), 0)))

#else   // NDEBUG
#define INSTANTIATE_ASSERT(fp)
#define ukd_assert(expr) ((void)0)
#endif  // NDEBUG
```

Can anyone tell me how to interpret this?

Comment: Which part(s) specifically are confusing?

Comment: I am not sure what ((void)((expr) ? 0 : (Assert::failedAssert(), 0))) does.  I know it calls the function failedAssert but not much else.

Comment: It's using a ternary operator. If `expr` evaluates to true, `ukd_assert(expr)` will evaluate to 0. Else, it'll call `Assert::failedAssert()` but still evaluate to 0.

Answer (score 0):

As from the comments to the question:

> I am not sure what ((void)((expr) ? 0 : (Assert::failedAssert(), 0))) does.  I know it calls the function failedAssert but not much else.

The fact is that the ternary operator requires that both operands are of the same type (you can freely ignore the few exceptions to this rule for your case).
Even though you didn't provide a declaration for `Assert::failedAssert()`, I strongly suspect that its return type is `void`. The comma operator makes possible to have `int` as the type of the expression:

```
(Assert::failedAssert(), 0)
```

Therefore the types of the two expressions of the ternary operator are `int` and the code happily compiles.

The first `(void)` just serves the purpose of suppressing a warning instead.